# z-index on jquery dialog not working inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap, which uses jquery dialog. If the z-index of the dialog is set to 1 or more works fine in the stand alone script. However, when I call the same script inside an iframe. Then the dialog shows underneath the other elements on the same page. Bizarrely enough, if I try to close the dialog, I can't because it seems that the semi-transparent layer is on top of the dialog itself.

```
ui-dialog {
    z-index:99999999 !important;
}
.ui-widget-overlay {
    position: fixed;
    z-index:99999999 !important;
}
.ui-dialog {
    z-index:99999999 !important;
}
.fixed-dialog {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    z-index:99999999 !important;
}
.ui-dialog-titlebar {
    border-left: 30px solid transparent;
    min-height:40px;
    background-color:#f09;
    background-image:url(images/yellow_alert_icon.png);
    background-position: -22px 8px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    z-index:99999999 !important;
}
```

I'm very stocked !!!

UPDATED CLARIFICATION:
The iframe is empty. It doesn't contain any other elements. I just use it as a dialog.
So the entire code inside the iframe is the same script. therefore, the parent script.
the parent script isolated works fine.
the moment I put it inside the iframe, when the jquery dialog pops up, it's showing underneath the parent script.

Comment: Are you saying it's appearing below other elements *inside* the iframe, or other elements on the containing page?

Comment: @meagar, below other elements on the containing page. But in stand alone shows fine.

Answer (score 2):

All elements of an `iframe` are isolated in that `iframe`. Any `z-index` value that is applied will be applied in relation to other elements inside the `iframe`.

The `iframe` itself can have a `z-index`, but that will affect the entire `iframe` and all it's contents. If you want one element in the `iframe` to appear above elements from the parent document, while other elements in the `iframe` are underneath, it isn't possible unfortunately.

Comment: Hi Andy, I updated my question. The iframe has no z-index. I just want the parent document, so behave the same way inside and outside the iframe.

Comment: Could you create a jsFiddle, or link to the site where you are having the problem?

Comment: I've tried to do a jsFiddle but didn't manage to replicate the behaviour. In my test it works fine, so I'll go thru my code and see if I find what's causing it and publish it, or see if I can at least replicate it.

Comment: Hi Andy, I found the error, and updated it. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I found my own error,

I hope this can help someone,

I had this piece of code which was bringing the .ui-widget-content one layer down when inside an iframe.

```
if($frame=='iframe'){
    echo'<style>
    .ui-widget-content{
    z-index:-1 !important;
...
```